# How to measure Picasso .fit()

Tags: android, picasso

After loading an image into a View, I want to be able to measure which part of a dedicated layout did load image occupy in order to have limits for moving annotation on tap & drag over the image. I must have these limits in order to restrict moving (up/down) of this annotation only to bitmap height.
Picasso Target does not help in this case, as it is loading a full width/height image, not resized by .fit().centerInside().
Currently, I am using a Pallete Callback, but I can ditch that if I need to use some custom callback to get the needed info in dips or whatever units)

```
Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(file)
                    .fit()
                    .centerInside()
                    .transform(PaletteTransformation.instance())
                    .into(oneImage, new PaletteTransformation.PaletteCallback(oneImage) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Palette palette) {
                            int bgColor = getBackgroundColor(palette);
                            if (bgColor != -1)
                                fullScreenLayout.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
                        }
                    });
```

[image: Image Annotation]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (which might be wrong) is that if you load image not directly to ImageView but rather into Target object, the Bitmap that you receive there will have exactly the dimensions you need. And then if you have like container of 600 pixels height and image 400px height -> easy to calculate vertical offset of 100 from top & bottom

Comment: Loading into Target will give me a Bitmap object of full width/height in pixels, which is not what I need. Picasso .fit().centerInside() is scaling that to "unknown" dimensions <- the ones I need.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a better (or not knowing of a solution directly from Picasso),
I implemented:

1. measuring imageView + measuring annotatingView
   (using ViewObserver)
2. and then used Picasso "to Target" loading (in parallel to loading to 
   imageView) to get bitmap dimensions and aspect ratio
3. based on original bitmap aspect ratio (it is .fit so it is going to
   consume full width or full height)
4. we can now calculate scaling factor, so it is obvious
5. if full width, and we know both bitmap width and imageView width, we also
   know scaled bitmap height consumed imageView

   ```
   private void measureHeights() {
   ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = imageLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
   if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
       viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
           @Override
           public void onGlobalLayout() {
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                   imageLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
               } else {
                   imageLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
               }
               imageViewWidth = imageLayout.getWidth();
               imageViewHeight = imageLayout.getHeight();
           }
       });
   }

   ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserverAnno = annotationLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
   if (viewTreeObserverAnno.isAlive()) {
       viewTreeObserverAnno.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
           @Override
           public void onGlobalLayout() {
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                   annotationLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

               } else {
                   annotationLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
               }
               annotationViewHeight = annotationLayout.getHeight();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }